# How to automatically link a word(s) to an external site every time it appears anywhere on the site?

Tags: hyperlink, automation, wordpress

For the life of me I do not know what the terminology is for this. And my search engine searches are straight up hopeless. I know I'm not the only one wanting to know this; I just don't know how to ask it or what keywords to use to figure this out on my own. So I'm here to explain it to you all the best I can in hopes someone might now and shed some light on my darkness. Okay here goes...

**Site page 1 content:**

Georgio went to the store after he stopped by to see how Nichols was doing.

**Site page 2 content:**

The cat was afraid of Georgio and his dog.

**Site page 3 content:**

My best friend is not a friend of Nichols, who is the best friend of Georgio, but is a friend of Georgio.

**What I need done:**

On each page (1, 2, 3) and each time it appears on each page, I want "Georgio" to be linked to the same external website (like http://geethr33whiskers.net <---I just made that up), but without me having to manually link each "Georgio". I want to be able to link "Georgio" once and then automatically the other instances will be linked to the same external website.

On each page (1, 3) and each time it appears on each page, I want "Nichols" to be linked to the same external website (like http://www.nichols2zzz4wedding.com <---I just made that up), but without me having to manually link each "Nichols". I want to be able to link "Nichols" once and then automatically the other instances will be linked to the same external website.

I hope this makes sense. If you know what I'm talking about, how do I set this up? I've got the site hosted on Netfirms (so it's not a wordpress.org site) with the WP blog platform set up on it. Or is there a WP plugin that will help me out doing this?

Also, what is this kind of process called? Oh, and I have tons of words that need this kind of automatic linking or whatever you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) to filter the text displayed.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'function_to_replace_text' );

function function_to_replace_text($content){
//add PHP code to replace your word by link in $content

return $content
}
```